# Print variable after pthread is done

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

How do I retain value of my global var BitArray after all the threads have been destroyed?
If I try printing the variable before terminating the thread it works but since the threads are executed in any order it is point less displaying values at this moment. Rather I want to print my variable after the threads have worked on it. 
Here's how I my code is. Thanks in advance :).
Declare BitArray global

```
int main(){

create some threads... to modify BitArray

PrintBitStreamData(BitArray, maxsize); //prints output

pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
pthread_join(threadid[0], &status);
pthread_exit(NULL);

PrintBitStreamData(BitArray, maxsize); //doesn't to anything


}
```

Comment: Join all the threads before output.

Comment: so I should put my output, PrintBitStreaData after pthread_join?

Comment: If you have multiple threads, join them all (one by one), you can not know which thread would terminate last.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aneri. I did something like this to end all threads and it worked.

//created

for (i = 0; i < max_threads; i++)
     pthread_create (&threadid[i],...)

//ended

...

```
for (i = 0; i < max_threads; i++){

    pthread_join (threadid[i],&status)

}
```

print results